# Asp net change hosting environment to Development

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to change my asp.net core hosting environment to development.
What I already did is :

1. Run this command:

   ```
   set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
   ```
2. Change the environment variables in system:

   [image]
3. Run these commands:

   ```
   dotnet restore

   dotnet watch run
   ```

I just see in the *projectName.csproj* file there is comment that say that **it run the production**, maybe that's the problem.

```
<Target Name="RunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec Command="npm install" />
<Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
<Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />
```

But for now what I see in my project is *Hosting environment : Production*
and I want to change it to environment because I can't see the changes in live when I change client side changes like HTML, CSS.

Comment: Can you run `echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%` from the command-prompt from where you run `dotnet watch run`? That'll confirm whether or not the environment variable is being set correctly.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 7):

To set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable in windows, run this command in cmd:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

Or

Use try in `web.config` like:

```
<configuration>
<!--
Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
 -->
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApplication.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

After setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable for your system you must open a new command window before running `dotnet run`.

Environment variables are cached for the lifetime of the shell, so an existing window won't pick up changes to the environment variable

I wrote a post on how to achieve this here: https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/#atthecommandline